# Accessing a javascript object within a for loop returns undefined

Tags: javascript, json, object, nested, traversal

I'm trying to access a nested javascript object within a for loop. The first level objects show up just fine, but the second level children show up as undefined. However if I do this outside a loop, hard-coding the object access, it works just fine. What is going on?

This is the object I'm trying to access:

```
var groups = {
  "group1": {
    "sum": 25,
    "count": 5
  },
  "group3": {
    "sum": 5,
    "count": 5
  }
}
```

See what I mean here: https://jsfiddle.net/97o1jme2/

Comment: Code should be posted **here**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use [`for ... in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

> The **`for...in`** statement iterates over the enumerable properties of an object, in arbitrary order. For each distinct property, statements can be executed.

which gives you a variable with the key of the object, you are iterating on.

Then you need the right [access](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) to the object, instead of `group["sum"]` use the key with `groups` together.

```
groups[group]["sum"]
//^^^^^^^^^^^
```

or

```
groups[group].sum
//^^^^^^^^^^^
```

```js
var groups = { group1: { sum: 25, count: 5 }, group3: { sum: 5, count: 5 } },
    group;

for (group in groups) {
  console.log("[Loop access] " + group + " - sum: " + groups[group].sum + " - count: " + groups[group].count);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that works like a charm. I would like to understand why this is happening though. I would assume the loop variable would be of type Object, why is it a String?

Comment: because you are iteratin over the keys of the object.

Comment: That `for..in` is **bad** ... Use `for..of` instead ...

Comment: @KarelG can you please explain why is for..in bad? I am facing a similar issue but find nothing to read ono

Comment: @AsmaRahimAliJafri the [`for..of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) MDN documentation has [a section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of#difference_between_for...of_and_for...in) about its difference towards `for..in`. Basically, the latter goes through all enumerable properties where as the former won't. It is important to know the differences between each other. I consider using `for..in` as a statement for exceptional use cases.

Answer (score 1):

If you perform `console.log(group)` in the loop you will see that at every iteration the `group` variable is not your desired `object` but it is a simple string - `key` of `groups` object. You would then access the proper object via `groups[group]` inside the loop.

**EDIT**

In order to be sure that you will obtain proper result I recommend you perform some validation inside the loop at every iteration

```
if ( groups.hasOwnProperty(group) ) {
    // perform operation
}
```

According to the documentation

> The hasOwnProperty() method returns a boolean indicating whether the object has the specified property.

Comment: I see, but I would assume the loop variable would be of type Object, why is it a String?

Comment: Because it iterates over properties of given object, that is how it is implemented.